# expo project, cannot load project to IPhone by scanning QR code, how to fix?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I can load the project by adding the url "exp://192.168.140:19000" on expo client on IPhone. But cannot load it by scanning QR code, which was what I was doing until having this problem.

These happens only when I set the expo XDE host to "local", other all fails.

The expo client display the error.

```
There was a problem loading the experience.
```

Show details display the following.

```
exp://localhost:19000
"Error while loading: Could not connect to the server.."(code -1004)
```

I want to be able to load the project by scanning QR code.
Could anyone help me on this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is : on expo XDE, set host to local, then click restart.

Answer (score 1):

IOS

open iphone camera scan the QR Scan code and it works. cheers.